# Python: read and write into files, and modify them with a function

Tags: python, function, file-io

I have a file named `Energy_vs_volume.dat` that looks like:

```
 # volume    energy   
    64       -180.001   
    63       -180.002
    62       -180.005
     .        .
     .        .
     .        .
```

I've already written a python script named `calculate.py` that contains a function.
I'd like to modify the python script named `calculate.py` in order to do the following:

**1)** Read `Energy_vs_volume.dat` file

**2)** Make this calculation: take the 1st column of `Energy_vs_volume.dat` file, which is the column "volume", and treat is as data of a variable `V`.

**3)** I have defined this function in the `calculate.py` script:

```
E0=-180.00
B0=55
V0=120 
B0_prime=20

def P(V): 
   f0=(3.0/2.0)*B0
   f1=((V0/V)**(7.0/3.0))-((V0/V)**(5.0/3.0))
   f2=((V0/V)**(2.0/3.0))-1
   pressure= f0*f1*(1+(3.0/4.0)*(B0_prime-4)*f2)
   return pressure
```

**4)** I need to give to the function the values of the 1st column from `Energy_vs_volume.dat` file (values of `V`) and create another file named `Pressure_vs_volume.dat` that would contain:

```
 # volume    pressure   
    64        the calculated value  
    63        the calculated value
    62        the calculated value
     .        .
     .        .
     .        .
```

**5)** Then I'd need to create a file named `Energy_vs_pressure.dat` that would contain:

**5a)** The 1st column: the data of the 2nd column from the `Pressure_vs_volume.dat` file

**5b)** The 2nd column: the data of the 2nd column from the `Energy_vs_volume.dat` file:

```
# pressure                   energy
 the calculated value        -180.001
 the calculated value        -180.002
 the calculated value        -180.005
     .                           . 
     .                           .
     .                           .
```

I would appreciate if you could help me

**EDIT**

If the `Energy_vs_volume.dat` has a 3rd column named `# velocity` :

```
 # volume    energy        velocity
    64       -180.001      25
    63       -180.002      21
    62       -180.005      22
     .        .            .
     .        .            .
     .        .            .
```

And I run the same script but with this line:

`volume, energy, velocity = [float(n) for n in line.split()]`

It is not capable of splitting, giving this error:

`volume, energy, extra = [float(n) for n in line.split()]
ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: Looking at a single line in those files, are there spaces or tabs and is the number and position of these spaces or tabs in the generated files important?

Comment: @timakro +1 and Thanks for your comment.  This story begins with only **one** input file: `Energy_vs_volume.dat`. As stated in the post, this file consists of a very first line where it says `# volume  energy` and from the second line and beyond, only two columns with numbers. _Looking at a single line_ in this file, the separation between the first and the second column is a tab

Comment: The output files are: `Pressure_vs_volume.dat` and `Energy_vs_pressure.dat`. In both, the very first line should contain, respectively, `# volume    pressure `  and `# pressure      energy`

Comment: it sounds like you are asking us to do homework for you. Reading and writing files is well documented, and there are likely millions of examples on the internet. What have you done to try to solve this problem for yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this is understandable.

```
# open the files
volume_energy = open('Energy_vs_volume.dat')
volume_pressure = open('Pressure_vs_volume.dat', 'w') # w for writing
pressure_energy = open('Energy_vs_pressure.dat', 'w') # w for writing

# write first lines of your created files
# (still not sure about the exact formatting)
# \t is a tab, \n is a newline
volume_pressure.write('# volume\tpressure\n')
pressure_energy.write('# pressure\tenergy\n')

with open('Energy_vs_volume.dat') as energy_volume: # open the file
    energy_volume.next() # skip the first line
    for line in energy_volume: # iterate over the remaining lines
        # split the lines (removes linebreaks, tabs and spaces)
        # convert all items to floats, unpack the list into two variables
        volume, energy = [float(n) for n in line.split()]
        pressure = P(volume) # call your function
        # write values to files
        # (still not sure about the exact formatting)
        volume_pressure.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(volume, pressure))
        pressure_energy.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(pressure, energy))

# close files
volume_energy.close()
volume_pressure.close()
pressure_energy.close()
```

When `Energy_vs_volume.dat` contains

```
# volume    energy
64  -180.001
63  -180.002
62  -180.005
```

the program creates a file `Pressure_vs_volume.dat` containing

```
# volume    pressure
64.0    887.265477926
63.0    963.895750396
62.0    1047.46825523
```

and a file `Energy_vs_pressure.dat` containing

```
# pressure  energy
887.265477926   -180.001
963.895750396   -180.002
1047.46825523   -180.005
```

Comment: If you test it, it gives this error: `volume, energy = [float(n) for n in line.split()]
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack`

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, it works for me: http://pastebin.com/RZLapnGy. You probably have empty lines in your input file or other lines that don't fit the format.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for this. A minor error is just that it should be `format(pressure, energy)` instead of `format(energy, pressure)` in order that in `Energy_vs_pressure.dat` the 1st column is the x-data and not the y-data to plot.

Comment: I am learning and of course it is not a matter of doing "homework" and run away... i do really want to learn python I 'd like to understand the meaning of each command. I am trying to understand how `[float(n) for n in line.split()]` works. As you've very well explained in the comments, it `converts all items to ints, unpack the list into two variables`. I would say that it `converts all items to floats`?

Comment: I have added an extra (3rd) column named `extra` in the`Energy_vs_volume.dat` file with the same number of rows of data, without spaces, and I wrote: `volume, energy, extra = [float(n) for n in line.split()]`, apparently it says: `ValueError: too many values to unpack` How does this work? Thanks

Comment: I fixed the order of the columns in `Energy_vs_pressure.dat` and the comment saying `int` instead of `float`.
`line.split()` returns a list of the numbers in string form. `[i+1 for i in number_list]` is called a list comprehension in python, this example evaluates to a list with all the items of `number_list` increased by 1. Finally `a, b, c = list_with_3_items` assigns the first item of `list_with_3_items` to `a`, the second one to `b` and so on.
I think my answer is correct now, please accept it if you see no further problems. Feel free to ask questions about the code in the comments.

Comment: Thanks +1 It should be `pressure_energy.write` instead of `energy_pressure.write`. If I have a 3rd column in `Energy_vs_volume.dat`, the splitting does not work: See **EDIT**

Comment: Fixed the variable name. I can't reproduce your new problem, it works for me. Note that the edit function should be used to correct mistakes and improve the understandability of your question, not to change it's content. I again think my answer is correct now, please accept it if you see no further problems.

Comment: +1 and tick to the answer. Thanks for all, this finally worked, included the splitting to three columns. Sorry for the wait, I have been making many trials to understand the code :)